# Fragment showing Old Data

Tags: android-fragments

I am new to android programming. I am implementing functionality to scan particular Inventory Item and search for the barcode if it already exists in an ArrayList. If it exists then I am replacing the current Scan fragment with the InvnetoryFound Fragment in which I have option to update quantity and completely remove item from ArrayList.

The issue I am facing is, after removing Inventory when I scan again for different Inventory barcode, upon successful scan, it is showing InventoryFound Fragment with old data that was removed from ArrayList. Below is my code:

Test ArrayList Code:

```
public static String[] inve = new String[5];
public static ArrayList<String[]> inventory_list = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    inve[0] = "INV45879";
    inve[1] = "Bridge Support Pipe";
    inve[2] = "Pre-insulated pipe supports provide both support and insulation in hot and cold piping applications.Pre-insulated pipe supports provide both support and insulation in hot and cold piping applications.";
    inve[3] = "0885370720679";
    inve[4] = "2";

    inventory_list.add(inve);

    inve = new String[5];

    inve[0] = "INV45880";
    inve[1] = "Cement";
    inve[2] = "Pre-insulated pipe supports provide both support and insulation in hot and cold piping applications";
    inve[3] = "9771234567003";
    inve[4] = "8";

    inventory_list.add(inve);
```

If scan is successful it calls below function to replace fragment:

```
private static void showFragment(Fragment fragment, String back_option) {

    try {
        // start transition
        FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        //if fragment Inventory is found then pass data to fragment
        if(back_option.equals("inventoryFound")){

             //sends found inventory list data to fragment

             String[] inv_data = inventory_list.get(inventory_index);
             Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
             bundle.putStringArray("inventory_data",inv_data);
             bundle.putInt("inventory_index",inventory_index);
             inventoryFoundFragment.setArguments(bundle);

             back_option = "null";


        // replace fragment
        if (!back_option.equals("null"))  // with back option
            ft.replace(R.id.frag_content, fragment).addToBackStack(back_option);
        else    // no back option
            ft.replace(R.id.frag_content, fragment);

        // commit
        ft.commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        out("PROBLEM SHOWING FRAGMENT!!!"+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

InventoryFound fragment populates data and works fine. Below is the code when I click on Remove populated Inventory:

```
public void removeInventory(){
    Shared.inventory_list.remove(inventory_index);
    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Inventory "+inventory_index+" Removed Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(this);
    ft.replace(R.id.frag_content, new ScanFragment());
    ft.commit();
}
```

It is removing successfully but when I scan it again e.g. for barcode "0885370720679" it shows the previous data on InventoryFound fragment. I have debugged it in Logcat (Log.d) and I am able to see correct data but it is not displaying in fragment.

any suggestions or guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem.

When Fragment is in foreground, it calls onResume() method. In this method I call user-defined function which re-sets the data for Fragment fields. I don't know if it's a correct to way to fix this issue but it's working for me now!